# Google Analytics hitCallback for every hit?

Tags: google-analytics

Is it possible to set a global [hitCallback in Google Universal Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#hitCallback):

So any hit, calls the same callback?

Without modifying each ga('send'..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't set the hit callback globally, but you *can* set it on the tracker object itself, which means it'll get called for every hit that tracker sends (which is probably just as good as globally, for your purposes).

Here's an example:

```
ga('create', 'UA-12345-1', 'auto');

ga('set', 'hitCallback', function() {
  console.log('hit is done');
});

ga('send', 'pageview');
ga('send', 'event', 'Button', 'click');
```

If you run this code, you'll see "hit is done" logged to the console twice.

Comment: Very nice, I thought that was just for setting additional data, but off course it could be used for setting any param. Thanks.